# The problem with using the Procedure in Pascal

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
uses GraphABC;
var 
  x, y, a: integer;

  procedure treug(x, y, a, b: integer);
  begin
    x := 0;
    y := 20;
    line(x, y, x+a, y);
    line(x, y, x, y+b);
    line(x+a, y, x, y+b);
  end;

begin
  writeln('Enter the length of the catheter'); 
  read(a);

  while y < 480 do
  begin
    y := y+1;
    treug(x, y, a, a);
  end;
end.
```

Outputs only one triangle, and not the desired number up to the vertical border.

I expected one vertical row of right triangles (x and y are the coordinates of the right angle) to the lower border of the graphic window.

Comment: You ignore the argument `x` and `y` in `treug()`, which sets `x` and `y` to what it wants. So you _would_ get 480 triangles, all in the exact same spot — except that the global loop `y` is not initialized to begin with, so IDK how many triangles you are actually getting.

Answer (score 1):

```
uses GraphABC;
var 
  x, y, a: integer;

  procedure treug(x, y, a, b: integer);
  begin
    line(x, y, x+a, y);
    line(x, y, x, y+b);
    line(x+a, y, x, y+b);
  end;

begin
  writeln('Enter the length of the catheter'); 
  read(a);

  x := 0;   // <-- initialize your x and y here
  y := 20;

  while y < 480 do
  begin
    y := y+1;   // (see note below)
    treug(x, y, a, a);
  end;
end.
```

Remember, you have *two* sets `x` and `y` variables:

- The global ones declared in the main program (and now properly initialized in the main program)
- The ones local to the `treug()` procedure.

Things may have the same name and not be the same thing. If it helps, you can think of the global `x` as `GraphABC.x` and the local `x` as `GraphABC.treug.x`.

BTW, you probably want to increment `y` by something more than `1` each time through the loop, otherwise it’ll look just like a single triangle has been smeared down the display. (You might want to increment by `b`.)

Comment: This appears to be PascalABC.Net code .. it compiles on my end using the PascalABC.Net IDE.